# Has anyone used online bank statements for a UK Visitor Visa

Tags: paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, uk-residents

Have any of you used online bank statements (i.e. print outs of the pdf documents from your online banking) to apply for a UK Visitor Visa?

If so, were they accepted or rejected?

**Please only reply if you have actually applied using the documents stated.** I am specifically looking for real experience rather than opinions.

Not a duplicate as this specifically asks for people with experience. I am very aware of the guidance stating the need for originals only, however, it is not black and white on whether online statements constitute originals. As stated - PLEASE ONLY REPLY IF YOU HAVE EXPERIENCE OF USING ONLINE STATEMENTS

Comment: Yes. Three times. Accepted in all cases although visa was denied in the third case for a different reason. I believe online statements are the norm, unless in parts of Africa like my original country where it probably won't carry much weight.

Comment: @blackhaj As you’ve no doubt already seen, the Visitor Visa guidance states that all documents must be originals, but is silent on whether online bank statements meet this criterion. For a definitive answer you could try emailing UKVI https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk

Comment: Why is it difficult for you get bank statements from the bank on official stationery ? If there is so much doubt on if online statements will be accepted or not, get the statements from the bank and get done with it.

Comment: Typically, once an account holder has opted for online statements (or indeed, these are the only type normally provided), it takes time to switch back to, or order specially,  statements. @Musonius Rufus did you get your online statements stamped by your bank before submitting them? My own U.K. bank has assured me that their online pdf statements are admissible in a court of law therefore acceptable for any other purpose, but without confirmation from UK gov sources it remains unclear. However I don’t recall any questions on TSE citing a refusal solely for submitting online statements.

Comment: @Traveller My statements were not stamped by a bank. Indeed the first time I went to get them stamped at Bank of America. They refused because they said it is acceptable as is for official purposes. Now like I wrote that might not be the case if applying in some of the developing countries (e.g. Nigeria) already noted for high incidence of fraudulent documents. In my home country Ghana for example bank statements are not printed on normal A4 sheets so a statement printed from online will be clearly physically different from one printed in a bank. I would not risk it. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: I've used them when giving supporting documents for my partner's family visa. But these were from UK banks. I know that's not a visitor visa but its probably a visa that gets scrutinised more, they were fine.

Comment: @BritishSam - useful to know. Mine will be from British banks too as I am using them to support my girlfriends application. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Three times. Accepted in all cases although visa was denied in the third case for a different reason. I believe online statements are the norm, unless in parts of Africa like my original country where it probably won't carry much weight.

My statements were not stamped by a bank. Indeed the first time I went to get them stamped at Bank of America. They refused because they said online statements are acceptable as is for official purposes.

Like I wrote that might not be the case if applying in some of the developing countries (e.g. Nigeria) already noted for high incidence of fraudulent documents. In my home country Ghana for example bank statements are not printed on normal A4 sheets so a statement printed from online on A4 sheets will be clearly physically different from one printed in a bank. I would not risk it. Better safe than sorry