# Can i use PayPal account statment for a UK Visitor Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I am working as an online freelancer-ebay seller-and i intend to apply for a UK visit visa as i want to visit london. All the money that i make through Ebay is transfered to my PayPal account, PayPal is provieding me with a monthly account statment showing all the month transactions-earnings and spendings-and my account info, i don’t have an ordinary bank account as paypal account does all what i need, can i apply for the visa with my paypal account statment to show my financial situation?

Comment: In theory yes, as PayPal is an authorised payment services provider in the EU for instance (in fact, IIRC they actually have a credit institution licence). However I wouldn’t be surprised if this was met with scepticism. Make sure the statement includes the fact that PayPal is properly registered as a financial institution (the details will vary based on your country of residence, as PayPal have many different entities with distinct licenses).

Comment: no the statment doesn’t show that, but i have noticed that the visa fees can be paid online with paypal!, which shows their acknowledge of paypal

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122826/has-anyone-used-online-bank-statements-for-a-uk-visitor-visa

Comment: @Traveller thank you for your help but that question is different from mine

Comment: Gayot Fow back in 2015 seemed to think that [PayPal wasn't very likely to be acceptable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/45681/3221). Perhaps things have changed by now. I miss him.

Comment: i still don’t have an answer!